# Windows Media Player - Can't find video codec for the file, will it still play the audio part?

Tags: video, audio, codec, windows-media-player

If I try to play a movie file, whose video codec WMP doesn't recognize, and assuming it does know the audio type, will it play just the audio ? or will it flash an error message and stop?
 How do I test this out?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, WMP will play just the audio, and display some "nice" visualization as a replacement for the missing video. If your movie has a known video codec but unknown audio codec, WMP will just play the video for you without sound.

Don't know how you would easiest go about testing it though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a set of video audio codecs. Here are the latest media codecs K-Lite Codeck Pack FULL http://depositfiles.com/ru/files/xupbyy482